# How to iterate a stream in Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to iterate through a stream in order to print the content.

```
type 'a stream = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a stream thunk and 'a thunk = unit -> 'a
```

This is where my function is called

```
|> iter_stream ~f:(fun (f,c,l) -> printf "%s %s %s\n" f c l)
```

And this is the type

```
let rec iter_stream st ~f 
(* val iter_stream : 'a stream -> ('a -> unit) -> unit *)
```

I can't seem to find any examples on how to implement it. The only idea I have is to think about it like a list which is obviously wrong since I get type errors.

```
let rec iter_stream st ~f =
match st with
| None -> ()
| Some(x, st') -> f x; iter_stream st' ~f
```

Comment: You can check how the stream module of the standard library is implemented : https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/28c337fecbebfc064c06ae0ba35a1107b0b58493/stdlib/stream.ml
Streams were also implemented in SklMl. You can get the source code here : http://sklml.inria.fr/archive/sklml-2.1+pl0.tgz

Answer (score 0):

Your stream is extremely similar to a list, except that you need to call a function to get the tail of the list.

Your proposed code has many flaws. The main two flaws that I see are:

1. You're using the constructors `None` and `Some` while a stream has constructors `Nil` and `Cons`.
2. You're not calling a function to get the tail of the stream. Note that in `Cons (a, b)`, `b` is a "stream thunk", i.e., it's a function that you can call to get a stream.

(Perhaps these are the only two flaws :-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh i see. Looking at the type of my stream using Some and None was indeed very random. The problem i'm running into now is that i don't know how to get the tail of the stream to pass it as argument to the recursive function. In this case when i match the stream with Cons(x, st') when i look at the type st' in this case is a' stream thunk. How do i turn a' stream thunk into a' stream.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Jeffrey, you should be matching the stream against `Nil` and `Cons`.

Now, `iter_stream` is very straightforward for a `Nil` stream: nothing should happen. I'm going to rearrange your parameters as it feels a bit more idiomatic that way.

```
let rec iter_stream ~f = function
  | Nil -> ()
```

Now, if we match the `Cons` constructor, we know the current value we're working on, and we have a *thunk* for the next stream. This thunk only becomes a stream we can call `iter_stream` on if we apply it to `unit`.

```
let rec iter_stream ~f = function
  | Nil -> ()
  | Cons (v, next) -> f v; iter_stream ~f @@ next ()
```